# Grignard reaction with cycloheptatriene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, grignard-reagent

I'm having trouble with the following set of reactions and their products.

> [image]
> Product **A** is achieved by exploiting the unique aromaticity of cycloheptatriene cations. When **A**  is treated with the Grignard reagent $\ce{MeMgI}$, a mixture of **B** and **C** is obtained. Treating **A** with catalytic amount of $\ce{HCl}$ in $\ce{CCl_4}$ furnishes isomer **A’**, which is again converted into a mixture of **B** and **C** upon treatment with Lewis-acidic Grignard reagents.

For **A** I got the following structure, since I could not figure out how the aromaticity of the first structure is affecting the reaction.

[image]

This cannot be correct, since the grignard reaction would produce only one product and not a mixture of two.

[image]

Having done some reasearch online on the resonance structures of cycloheptatriene, I thought of the following structure for **A**. But this would not produce two different products either if I am not mistaken.

[image]

Comment: I think your initial structure for A is correct. Consider that MeMgI can attack A in a 1,2 mode or 1,4

Comment: Would that result in the products **B** and **C** being 1) the one below my structure for **A** and the other 2) being the same as 1) but with methyl group moved to the adjacent carbon in the cycloheptatriene structure?

Comment: 1) correct  2) Me group in the benzylic position on benzocycloheptadiene ring - like your last structure but without the OH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The product **A**, shown below, is formed by first reducing the ketone to a secondary alcohol with $\ce{LiAlH_4}$ and then by adding a methyl group to form an ether using the reagent $\ce{CH_3I}$.

$\hskip2in$ [image: A]

Next the grignard reaction with product **A** will form two products. The grignard reagent $\ce{MeMgI}$ can attack **A** in a $1$,$2$ or in a $1$,$4$ mode, due to the unique aromaticity of cycloheptatriene, giving a mixture of products **B** and **C**, the structures of which are shown below.

$\hskip1in$[image: B]
[image: C]